# How do I store/share data between different devices?

Tags: sql, iot

I am creating an IoT system of sensors etc. for my house. Each sensor is run on a Raspberry Pi Zero. I want all the data to be stored somewhere so that a separate Zero can run a web app using flask and also display the data on an LCD display, and I also want the data to be accessible by an iOS app that I am creating in Xamarin (since I don't have a Mac to use XCode on...) I figured, that SQL would be the best for storing this data and the SQL server would be run on the Zero with the display and web app and so I tried that using MySQL. The problem I ran into, is that only one device can access the database at one time.

Is there a SQL client that allows multiple connections at one time ? Is there a different solution to sharing this data ?

I would be thankful for any insight on this.

Comment: Every single SQL client library supports multiple concurrent connections to a shared server, and in fact it's done on pretty much all websites and programs using a RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL allows multiple processes to access the database simultaneously, but processes may lock tables so that other processes can't access them.  Your problem with multiple client connections may have more to do with the application design (with respect to database usage) than the DBMS you're using.